# Using Wireshark in Computer Networks

Tags: networking, wireshark

How to find the total number of IP addresses observed in a trace?

I tried using "conversations" and "IP addresses", which are under statistics option, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to
Statistics -> Endpoints -> tab: IPv4

Click on Address to sort the column.
Click on Copy to copy the list values to the clipboard.

You can find more information in the [Wireshark User's Guide](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatEndpoints.html#ChStatEndpointsWindow).